# Pentaho 5.1 Community Edition Login Error

Tags: authentication, pentaho

I've installed Pentaho 5.1 community edition with mySql on my Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) following this tutoral: 
http://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/pentaho-bi-server-5-0-1ce-mysql-installation-guide
(being carefull from the step five and not erasing the class attributes from some tags).
I can access the login page but I am not able to login. I've tried all known possible cases: admin, Admin, Suzy and suzy (for the user) and "password" for the password, but it's not working. I always get the error message: "A login error occurred. Please try again."

Can someone help me? I have no idea what to do :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was happening because I was using Java 8 and the compiler used in Pentaho works with the versions 6 and 7. Since the 8 was installed, something was setting the compiler to use Java 5 by default, and that is why I was getting the error.
I uninstalled Java 8 and installed 7.

Comment: Pentaho doesnt work for java 1.8? I think it should work for any java above 1.6.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal Pentaho CE BI Server 5.0.x works only with Java 1.6, 1.7 Pentaho CE BI Server 6.0.x is expected to work with Java 1.8.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that a while ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out our server has automatically upgraded to Java 8 the night before the problems started. I have also uninstalled java 8 and installed java 7 and it works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server logs (catalina.out and pentaho.log in tomcat/logs). Maybe there's more info there.

Comment: I couldn't really find anything when looking on the file...
if u could take a look, I'd really appreciate!
here is the file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50723992/catalina.out updated after trying the last time.

Comment: What Java version are you running ? From the log files, it seems you're running a version inferior to 1.5 ? Make sure you're at least using jdk/jre 1.6